# ListView in OnpostExecute and display respective info

Tags: android

Sir I have written code for custom list view it is perfectely fine but i want to write code for onitem click listenet  in onpostexecutemethod and show respective info according to my ticket. i want to show all ticket info of selected item.

```
 class viewticket extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(UserLogedIn.this);
        pdialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        pdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pdialog.setCancelable(false);
        pdialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)  {
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", u_id));
       // JSONObject jsonArray = jpar.makeHttpRequest(URLMyTicket, "POST", param);

        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();


        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URLMyTicket, ServiceHandler.POST, param);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null)

        {
            try {

                contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                 a=contacts.length();
                Log.v(TAG, ".................." + a);

                if(a > 0 ) {
                    id = new String[contacts.length()];
                    stats = new String[contacts.length()];
                    due_date = new String[contacts.length()];
                    prob = new String[contacts.length()];

                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String aa = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String bb = c.getString(TAG_PROB);
                        String cc = c.getString(TAG_status);
                        String dd = c.getString(TAG_due_date);

                        Log.v(TAG, "TAG_ID" + aa);
                        Log.v(TAG, "TAGPROB" + bb);
                        Log.v(TAG, "TAGPROB" + cc);
                        Log.v(TAG, "TAGPROB" + dd);

                        id[i] = aa;
                        prob[i] = bb;
                        stats[i] = cc;
                        due_date[i] = dd;

                        Log.v(TAG, "aaaaa" + id[i]);
                        Log.v(TAG, "bbbbb" + prob[i]);
                        Log.v(TAG, "cccc" + stats[i]);
                        Log.v(TAG, "dddd" + due_date[i]);


                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
              System.out.print("hiiiiiiiiiiii" );
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String  result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog

        Log.v(TAG, "length of aaaaa" + a);
        if(id!=null && id.length > 0 )
        {
            Ticket_adapter adapter=new Ticket_adapter(UserLogedIn.this,id,prob,stats,due_date,stimg);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
         lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               //how to write code to send ticket releated data to next activity of respective ticket

             }
         });
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(UserLogedIn.this, "No Ticket Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        pdialog.hide();
        pdialog.dismiss();  

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ticket data is being held in a model class, `Ticket` or something of the sort, I would suggest having it implement `Parcelable` and then passing it to the related activity in the intent, `intent.putExtra(String, Parcelable)`, and then recreating the model class in the new activity with the parcelable data `new Ticket(Parcelable)`. If it is just a small amount of info (names, numbers, etc.) just pass them directly though the intent, `intent.putExtra(String, String)`.